# What is the interactive explanation of a number to the power $\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: complex-numbers

What happens when a number is multiplied with itself i times, i.e a number $n \in \mathbb{C}$, what is the explanation of $n^i$ ?

I have tried a few by myself:-
$e^i = cos \; 1 + i sin\; 1$ and
$i^i$ is a pure real number.

What about others ? What is $1^i$ ?

Comment: if $1=e^{2i\pi}$ then $1^i=e^{-2\pi}$

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to be much more careful.  Notice this
$$i^i = (e^{\pi/2 + 2\pi i n})^i =(?) e^{i \pi/2}e^{-2\pi n} = -e^{-2\pi n} $$
for every integer $n$.  You have run square up against the complex log here. And that requires real care.

Comment: It should be added as a comment.